# Access attribute of one instance from another instance defined in that instance

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

Sorry for the confusing question.

Say there are two instances of two different classes (e.g. 'big_instance' and 'little_instance').
The little_instance is defined as an attribute of the big instance.
How would a method in the little class access an attribute of the big instance.

An example is below. 
The line 'return parent.attribute1' is basically pseudo code. How would this line be written properly?

```
class BigClass:
    def __init__(self, att):
        self.attribute1 = att
        self.little_instance = LittleClass()

class LittleClass:
    def parents_att(self):
        return parent.attribute1

big_instance = BigClass(1)
print(big_instance.little_instance.parents_att())
```

Comment: The LittleClass instance doesn't automatically receive any information about the BigClass instance. If you want the LittleClass instance to know about the BigClass instance, you're going to have to give it that information explicitly.

Comment: This makes sense, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah yes I got it. Read the comments for explanation.

The test code at the end shows that it works even after attribute1 changes :)

```
class BigClass:
    def __init__(self, att):
        self.attribute1 = att
        # pass in self
        self.little_instance = LittleClass(self)

class LittleClass:
    def __init__(self, the_big_class):
        # the big class is held in an instance var
        self.the_big_class = the_big_class

    def parents_att(self):
        # the instance var is used to reference the attribute
        return self.the_big_class.attribute1

big_instance = BigClass(1)
print(big_instance.little_instance.parents_att())
big_instance.attribute1 = 2
print(big_instance.little_instance.parents_att())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following if you want to access attribute from BigClass into LittleClass.

```
class BigClass:
    def __init__(self, att):
        self.attribute1 = att


class LittleClass(BigClass):
    def __init__(self, att):
        BigClass.__init__(self, att)

    def parent_att(self):
        return self.attribute1


small_instance = LittleClass(1)
print(small_instance.parent_att)
```

Comment: In this solution small_instance is not defined within an instance of the BigClass :/ Sorry but inheritance won't do, simply wondering if it is possible to access the attribute as shown.